# Public Platform Events which can be subscribe by any Salesforce Org

Tags: platform-event, public

We would like to generate a public platform event which will be published on a single Salesforce org and it can be consumed by any other Salesforce Org.

Few examples of this public platform event would be:

- Weather alert from Government, which can be consumed by different orgs.
- Flight schedules/notifications

I couldn't find anywhere about public platform event. Please suggest, if it is feasible in Salesforce or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is feasible. You will need to use the Streaming API to push the notifications to other orgs. The question will also be one of how do you plan to receive them? Unless you have some other means of polling for them, most likely you will also need to subscribe to them using the Streaming API.